# Как расположить картинки по горизонтали?

Tags: php

Этот код выводит на экран картинки с flickr столбиком. Как можно сделать так, чтобы картинки расположились друг за другом по горизонтали?

```
foreach ($photos['photos']['photo'] as $photo)
{
    echo "<div class=\"abc\"><img src=\"" . $f->buildPhotoURL($photo, "Square") ."\" width=\"80\" height=\"80\" alt=\"$photo[title]\" /></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<div class=\"abc\">";
foreach ($photos['photos']['photo'] as $photo)
{
    echo "<img src=\"" . $f->buildPhotoURL($photo, "Square") ."\" width=\"80\" height=\"80\" alt=\"$photo[title]\" />";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Но мне нужно, чтобы картинки были в отдельных блоках, я еще должен задать за них функцию `droppable`.

Comment: в span'ах размещайте, дивы проблематично в ряд выстраивать